# child component not get display while using router-outlet active event to get child component instance

Tags: html, angular, angular8, router-outlet, angular-cli-v8

While using router-outlet, i have used “**active**” event ton take child component instance.

> A router outlet will emit an activate event any time a new component
>   is being instantiated, and a deactivate event when it is being
>   destroyed.

**Sample** - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-a9jpsd?file=app/app.component.ts

Example code –

> App.component.html

```html
<div class="container">
    <router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)"></router-outlet>
  </div>
```

> App.component.ts

```js
public onRouterOutletActivate(event : any) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

But child component not get displayed at initial loading, but element is in DOM.

Any idea about this problem?

Comment: Which child component you mean ejs-dashboardlayout ?

Comment: yes..when you do some changes in sample then it will get displayed

Answer (score 0):

Return the boolean value for which (activate) is looking for:

```
public onRouterOutletActivate(event : any) {
    if(event){
      console.log(event);
      return true;
    }else{ return false; }
}
```

And also just check in app.component.html, if you are calling the same onRouterOutletActivate function on (activate):

```
(activate)="onRouterOutletActivate($event)"
```

Hope it works for you now !!!

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-vjuzvn?file=app/app.component.ts no luck for me

Comment: There is some issue with your css because of which you are not able to see your login component calling. Hardcode some message in your login.component template and then your can see it calling clearly.

Comment: sorry, i cant understand

Comment: Go to login.component.ts and replace template with below:  template: `Hello
  <div>
      <ejs-dashboardlayout id='defaultLayout' #defaultLayout [panels]='panels' [columns]="5">
    </ejs-dashboardlayout>
    </div>
  `,

Comment: again same issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-dfnnkm?file=app/views/login/login.component.ts

Comment: When you do inspect element, login components is present there which means this is not the issue with displaying child component through router-outlet but actually there is some issue with your sidebar <ejs-dashboardLayout> </ejs-dashboardLayout> which is not letting displayed your child component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206699/discussion-between-swati-gupta-and-kumaresan-sd).